# Regex get last occurrence of the pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string and I need to select the last occurrence of the pattern.
The string is:

> [[[1302638400000.0, 0], [1302724800000.0, 610.64999999999998],
>   [1302811200000.0, 2266.6500000000001], [1303156800000.0,
>   4916.9300000000003], [1303329600000.0, 6107.3199999999997], [1303934400000.0, 9114.6700000000001]], [[1302638400000.0, 20000.0],
>   [1302724800000.0, 20000.0], [1302811200000.0, 20000.0],
>   [1303156800000.0, 20000.0], [1303329600000.0, 20000.0],
>   [1303934400000.0, 20000.0]], [[1302638400000.0, 20000.0],
>   [1302724800000.0, 20610.650000000001], [1302811200000.0,
>   22266.650000000001], [1303156800000.0, 24916.93], [1303329600000.0, 26107.32], [1303934400000.0, 29114.669999999998], [1304452800000.0, 30078.23]], **[[1302718580000.0, 0.0], [1302772440000.0, 3.0532500000000073], [1303107093000.0, 11.333250000000007], [1303107102000.0, 21.753250000000008], [1303352295000.0,
>   24.584650000000003], [1303352311000.0, 26.8766], [1303815010000.0, 30.536599999999996], [1303815028000.0, 27.703349999999993]]];**

The pattern that I use is:

```
\s\[\[(.*?)\]\]
```

Which unfortunately selects only 1st occurrence. The highlighted text is the desired result. It doesn't matter how many square brackets at the end, just need the last array set.

UPDATE:
If it can help you, then the coding is in c#

Answer (score 59):

Use the `RightToLeft` option:

```
Regex.Match(s, @"\[\[(.*?)\]\]", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

This option is exclusive to the .NET regex flavor, and does exactly what you asked for: searches from the end of the input instead of the beginning.  Of particular note, the non-greedy `?` modifier works just as you expect; if you leave it off you'll get the whole input, but with it you get:

`[[1302718580000.0, 0.0], [1302772440000.0, 3.0532500000000073], [1303107093000.0, 11.333250000000007], [1303107102000.0, 21.753250000000008], [1303352295000.0, 24.584650000000003], [1303352311000.0, 26.8766], [1303815010000.0, 30.536599999999996], [1303815028000.0, 27.703349999999993]]]`

Comment: So simple, yet so unknown.

@Harry That's the most commonly asked question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

Do a greedy match up to the last set of `[[` and capture..

```
.*(\[\[.*\]\])\];
```

See it [here](http://rubular.com/r/WbNifNQ7ND).

Comment: Looks like it works for Ruby. I'm using c# and I'm using different website to check regex experssions:
http://regexr.com?334dc
and it selects the whole string unfortunately

Comment: The regex matches the whole string, but the part you're interested in is captured in group #1 (in C# you would use 'Group[1].Value` to extract it).  This technique works in every flavor, but .NET also offers a neater option, as my answer explains.

Comment: @AlanMoore is correct, generally this is the only way to do it without being able to specify the occurrence (which is language specific). As the question had no reference to `C#` I could only provide the best language agnostic solution, in future be sure to add all relevant information to the question. +1 for `RightToLeft`.

Answer (score 5):

There should be a global flag or a method that returns all matches in your language. Use this and take the last match.

In C# `Matches()` returns a `MatchCollection` containing all found matches. So you can do for example this:

```
string source = "[[[1302638400000.0, 0], [1302724800000.0, 610.64999999999998], [1302811200000.0, 2266.6500000000001], [1303156800000.0, 4916.9300000000003], [1303329600000.0, 6107.3199999999997], [1303934400000.0, 9114.6700000000001]], [[1302638400000.0, 20000.0], [1302724800000.0, 20000.0], [1302811200000.0, 20000.0], [1303156800000.0, 20000.0], [1303329600000.0, 20000.0], [1303934400000.0, 20000.0]], [[1302638400000.0, 20000.0], [1302724800000.0, 20610.650000000001], [1302811200000.0, 22266.650000000001], [1303156800000.0, 24916.93], [1303329600000.0, 26107.32], [1303934400000.0, 29114.669999999998], [1304452800000.0, 30078.23]], [[1302718580000.0, 0.0], [1302772440000.0, 3.0532500000000073], [1303107093000.0, 11.333250000000007], [1303107102000.0, 21.753250000000008], [1303352295000.0, 24.584650000000003], [1303352311000.0, 26.8766], [1303815010000.0, 30.536599999999996], [1303815028000.0, 27.703349999999993]]];";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s\[\[(.*?)\]\]");

MatchCollection result = r.Matches(source);

if (result.Count > 0) {
    Console.WriteLine(result[result.Count - 1]);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("No match found!");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @user1333853, I added a C# solution

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the $ to your pattern like this `\s\[\[(.*?)\]\]\]\;$`  and let me know if it works.

Currently I don't have bash under hand so I cannot check but it should do the trick.

Edit : Right version `\S+\s?+(?!((.*\[\[)))`

which translates into :

```
\S   : all alfanumeric
\s?  : all 1 space occurences
?!   : not 
.*   : everything
\[\[ : until the last pattern of [[ (excluded)
```

[Here is the Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/97THBqz2iU)

BTW great tool rubular, make me wanna look more into ruby and regular expressions :D

Comment: true, thought after ti unescape the ";"

Comment: Still over matches and `bash` isn't required to check as many site exists such http://rubular.com/

Comment: nope, this one selects everything startig from the first occurrence on  [[

Comment: Remove path name from file names: .*\\([A-Za-z0-9_$.]+)$

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to find the last instance/occurrence of a specific substring within a list of lines, where all lines in the list already contain the substring, you can use the following pattern.

### Pattern

```
.*AXDC(?![\s\S]*AXDC).*
```

Where **AXDC** is your substring.

### Input

```
this is line 1 with AXDC
this is line 2 with AXDC
this is line 3 with AXDC
this is line 4 with AXDC
```

### Match

```
this is line 4 with AXDC
```

### Pattern Explanation

- *.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
- * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- *AXDC* matches the characters AXDC literally (case sensitive)
- Negative Lookahead (?![\s\S]*AXDC)

  - \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
  - \S matches any non-whitespace character (equivalent to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
- *.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
- * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Any online regex matcher tool can be used to get a better explanation for the above pattern. [regex101](https://regex101.com/)